# Why is relying on reflection inadvisable?

Tags: java, reflection, jvm

Lots of websites and books I have read have stated that:

> relying on `reflection` in Java is a bad idea and you should seek other ways of testing/interfacing with encapsulated objects.

However, I can't find any actual reasons for this, is it to do with security managers being different from JVM to JVM? Or are there other reasons on top of this?

Comment: It generally causes your program to slow down, and isn't even necessary unless you're doing some far-out meta-programming. A lot of the time people ask "how can I do this with reflection", the answer is "don't use reflection".

Comment: From what I can tell, reflection is subject to performance impact, and the code isn't generally clean or easily maintained. This In addition to security managers possibly providing an issue, I wouldn't really say that there should be much issues in using reflection, it's just considered bad practice.

Comment: Cross site (kind of) dupe: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101187/are-there-problems-with-using-reflection

Comment: To add to what @Wayne has stated about maintenance, usually reflection involves hard-coding a String parameter for the package/classes needed to be retrieved. Refactoring will likely not catch those Strings and cause some bugs. Probably easy to find bugs, but maintenance work nonetheless

Comment: Look how ugly it is: `System.out.println(Class.forName(cntr.getClass().getCanonicalName()).getField("str").toString());`

Comment: ^ I see it for plugins that contain unknown classes more often than a hardcoded string, in which case refactoring should not be affected.

Comment: @zlakad, you should be using `getField(String).getValue()` instead. Also, you added code that wasn't necessary. `Class.forName(cntr.getClass().getCanonica‌​lName())` would simply be `cntr.getClass()`

Comment: @Wane If I have a field `String str;` ? Also I added extra getCanonicalName() just for showing ugliness!

Comment: @zlakad yes, that is correct. you want the value of the field, not the string representation of the field object.  Note that I used a javadoc-type refrence for the call. an example reference would be `getField("str").getValue()`

Comment: @Wayne Oh, I forgot when I wrote this (and why). Probably for some debugging... That's why used console to print is there a Field "str" in cntr, and what is the full name of "str" field. Looong time ago...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reflection can be very helpful in quite a few ways. One of the best examples is creating a program that allows for third party plugins. Reflection is great for that. However, using it otherwise results in the potential for a lot of other problems, including more runtime errors instead of compile errors, slower invocation, and (not always a HUGE problem) refactor and code analysis problems with IDE’s.

Generally, if you think you can do something without reflection, then do it without reflection. There is a very small grey area where reflection is a good idea. Finding that grey area takes practice.

Comment: Reflection should be a last resort compared to writing natural Java code, though in certain cases, it is the best option available. +1